# расширения Сhrome выполнить скрипт на загруженной странице

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю расширение
В background.js успешно отлавливаю событие

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab){
       //что-то делаю с url загруженной страницы
});
```

но как только пытаюсь выполнить на этой странице скрипт - никакой реакции (видимо потому, что страница все еще загружается или еще что-то)

Пытаюсь так:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:"alert('ok');"});
});
```

Не идет

Но при этом все работает, когда например выполняю скрипт в активной вкладке (но другой, уже загруженной) с помощью `chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tab){...});`

А необходимо выполнить скрипт именно в загруженной вкладке

`setTimeout` - не помогает

Какие выходы есть из такой проблемы?

Comment: Попробуйте просто вызвать console.log() в chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) { }  работает ?

Comment: @Arsen `alert()` - точно работает, открывается окошко алерта прямо посередине хрома от имени моего расширения

Comment: @Arsen задержка на 10 секунд помогла

Comment: setTimeout  - это костыль )) не самое лучшее решение, уверен что есть более оптимальное решение, просто пока смутно понимаю структуру ваших файлов и логику работы. Пробовали добавить отдельный popup.js подключить к popup.html и там вызвать вашу функцуию?

Comment: @Arsen тоже немного вас не понял))
Я вызываю функцию не в popup, а в backround, потому что мы событие можем отловить только в background, разве нет?
Или вы имеете в виду просто отдельно вызвать функцию на popup без привязки к событию?

Comment: А при каком событии должна работать ваша функция?

Comment: @Arsen `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`

Comment: Да, это должно норм(без задержек) работать в background.js, хмм странно. Попробуйте поменять на onActivated

Comment: @Arsen вот-вот) пока что буду костылиться))

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на onActivated

Comment: @Arsen `onActivated` - это переход на вкладку?
А если она не загружена, то выполнение моей функции будет бессмысленно, она у меня должна менять HTML в зависимости от url вкладки

Comment: Если вы работаете в HTML DOM - конечно это не поможет, я думал вы в расширении что то делаете, ну тогда костыль в помощь ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` вызывается при обновлении состояния вкладки. Таких событий происходит несколько в момент загрузки вкладки. Окончание загрузки – лишь одно из них.

Вам необходимо отслеживать свойство статус загрузки (status):

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) { 
    if(changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        // вот теперь вклада загрузилась окончательно
    }
});
```